# how to modify a calendar

Tags: java, calendar

I need to insert into two columns called: BeginHour and EndHour dates ans times which are in calendar type.

I have a method which generates the BeginHour, then i modify it to be EndHour. Finally i call my DAO method to insert them in my table.

The problem is that i find the last modification of variable 'cal' into the two columns.

for example if BeginHour is 2014-03-24 15:23:10 the EndHour should be 2014-03-24 15:28:20
but in my table i find the EndHour : 2014-03-24 15:28:20 into the two columns.

```
Calendar cal = mock.randomBeginHour();
        consoApp.setBeginHour(cal);  
    cal.add(Calendar.MINUTE, +5);
    cal.add(Calendar.SECOND, +10);
        consoApp.setEndHour(cal);
        dao.addConsoAppel(consoApp)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the same `Calendar` object reference for both `beginHour` and `endHour`. Create two different `Calendar`s instead. You can easily create another `Calendar` instance using `Calendar#getInstance()` and assign the time in the first calendar to set the start time for the other. In code:

```
Calendar cal = mock.randomBeginHour();
consoApp.setBeginHour(cal);
Calendar cal2 = Calendar.getInstance();
cal2.setTime(cal.getTime());
cal2.add(Calendar.MINUTE, +5);
cal2.add(Calendar.SECOND, +10);
consoApp.setEndHour(cal2);
dao.addConsoAppel(consoApp);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because the value of the variable cal is being passed by reference. So both beginHour and endHour are getting the same value. You should create a new Calendar instance for the endHour,assign its value to beginHour, and then do the addition

Comment: *This is because the value of the variable cal is being passed by reference* Java **never** passes by reference, it passes by value. In this case, it passes a copy of the reference (which is a value pointing to the same reference).